# Is there way to construct frequency dictionary of numbers without cycles('for') and in one line?

Tags: python

Suppose we have an array of numbers with repetitions.
Is there way to construct frequency dictionary of numbers without cycles ('for') and in one line? For instance, use list comprehension or map. I attempted but I couldn't come up with better :

```
d_num = {}
for number in x:
    d_num.update({number : 1} if d_num.get(number) == None else {number : d_num.get(number) + 1})
```

Comment: What did you attempt? Code is a much better describer than words. Sounds like what you want is `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python follows the philosophy of [**batteries included**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0206/) and in your case you could simply use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(x)
```

If you want it as plain dictionary you can convert it back easily. However `Counter` behaves (almost) like a dictionary so there should be almost no need:

```
dict(Counter(x))
```